# how to pass variable in url contain value of & sign in php without any decoding and encoding

Tags: php

My URL is:

```
http://www.dotcue.in/sandp_symf/web/customercare/cancelinvoice?id=753&&invoiceid=S&P LS MWext-1-D307-2271
```

I need to get invoiceid value in template.

Comment: I'd understand if you already receive the URL that way and you need to extract the information but, what do you mean with "pass variable"? Is it you the one that generates the URL after all? Why does it need to be malformed?

Comment: "i'm bored, solve my problem while i do something else. ktnxbye"

Answer (score 4):

Use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode):

```
$url = 'http://www.dotcue.in/sandp_symf/web/customercare/cancelinvoice'
$url .= '?id=' . $id . '&invoiceid=' . urlencode('S&P LS MWext-1-D307-2271');
```

In your template use:

```
echo $_GET['invoiceid'];
```

Comment: @user2235324 - Of course it's working, it's encoding the URL properly. But you said encoding is *not* an option.